# SequelizeJS HasOne association error

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I am relatively new to NodeJS and SequelizeJS and am facing a `hasOne` issue with a query I am building and I'd like to know your thoughts about this issue to find out where I gone wrong and the correct way to implement this query.

[Association Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr1Oj.png)

The models where generated using sequelize-auto (pg-hstore).

**Bloco Model:**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('bloco_condominio', {
    id_bloco: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    id_condominio: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'condominio',
        key: 'id_condominio'
      }
    },
    nm_bloco: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    ic_status: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: "A"
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'bloco_condominio'
  });
};
```

**Apartamento Model:**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('apartamento', {
    id_apartamento: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    id_condominio: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'condominio',
        key: 'id_condominio'
      }
    },
    nu_apto: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    id_bloco: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'bloco_condominio',
        key: 'id_bloco'
      }
    },
    ic_status: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: "A"
    },
    dt_incl: {
      type: DataTypes.TIME,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: sequelize.fn('now')
    },
    dt_ult_alt: {
      type: DataTypes.TIME,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: sequelize.fn('now')
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'apartamento'
  });
};
```

**Apartamento Service:**

```
"use strict";
var model = require('../models');
var Utils = require('../utils/utils');

var service = {};
var Apartamento = model.apartamento;
var Bloco = model.bloco_condominio;
var Morador = model.morador;
var Pessoa = model.pessoa;

//Incluir relação OneToMany
Apartamento.hasMany(Morador, { as: "Moradores", foreignKey: 'id_apartamento' });
Morador.belongsTo(Apartamento, { foreignKey: 'id_apartamento' });

Morador.hasMany(Pessoa, { as: "Pessoa", foreignKey: 'id_pessoa' });
Pessoa.belongsTo(Morador, { foreignKey: 'id_pessoa' });

Bloco.hasMany(Apartamento, { as: "Bloco", foreignKey: 'id_bloco' });
Apartamento.hasMany(Bloco, { foreignKey: 'id_bloco' }); 

service.getApartamentoById = function(idApartamento) {
    return Apartamento.findById(idApartamento, {
            include: [
                { model: Morador, as: 'Moradores', include: [
                    { model: Pessoa, as: 'Pessoa'}
                ]},
                { model: Bloco, as: 'Bloco' }
            ]
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            return data;
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            throw 'Erro ao consultar apartamento por ID: ' + err.message + ' - Request: '+JSON.stringify(idApartamento);
        });
};
```

I can  perfectly retrieve the other hasMany associations, but still hasn't found a way to do so in the reverse way.

Do you guys have any idea of how I should approach this issue in the correct manner?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Best regards,
Enrico Bergamo

Comment: where is your `hasOne` relation?

Comment: It's the Bloco/Apartamento relation. I am sorry, I tried so many different combinations that when I posted this question it was as a double hasMany relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it simpler for me (only knowing English), I've grabbed the following from Google translate:

```
Pessoa: Person
Morador: Dweller
Bloco: Block
Apartmento: Apartment
```

So, Dweller can have many People, an Apartment can have many Dwellers and a Block can have many Apartments.

Your definition on the other models indicates they're all 1:m, so I followed that assumption for Apartments and Blocks.

With that in mind, the following should work.

```
Bloco.hasMany(Apartamento, { as: "Apartmento", foreignKey: 'id_bloco' });
Apartamento.belongsTo(Bloco, { foreignKey: 'id_bloco' });
```

> Note: I've changed the `as: "Bloco"` to `as: "Apartmento"` and the second `hasMany` to `belongsTo`.  This might be where your issues were coming from.

---

**Edit:** The method to access the Apartments that belong to a Block is:

```
bloco.getApartmento(options)
```

I have this working with this promise chain:

```
Bloco.create()
.then(block => {
  return Promise.all([
    block,
    Apartamento.bulkCreate([{
      id_bloco: block.id_bloco
    }, {
      id_bloco: block.id_bloco
    }, {
      id_bloco: block.id_bloco
    }, {
      id_bloco: block.id_bloco
    }, {}])
  ])
})
.spread((bloco, apartment) => {
  return bloco.getApartamento()
})
.then(apartments => {
  console.log(apartments.length); --> Logs 4 which matches the bulk create.
})
```

---

If I've misinterpreted, and it should be an n:m relationship (Apartments/Blocks), then you should use belongsToMany on each model and identify the `through` option.

```
Bloco.belongsToMany(Apartamento, { 
    as: "Apartmentos", 
    foreignKey: 'id_bloco', 
    through: "BlocoAparmento" 
});
Apartamento.belongsToMany(Bloco, { 
    as: "Blocos", 
    foreignKey: 'id_apartmento', 
    through: "BlocoAparmento" 
});
```

This will create an n:m joining table called "BlockApartmento". If you define that model, and use the model instead of the string, you'll have complete control over the models settings.

This will give you the `Bloco.getApartmentos(` methods as well as opposite (`Apartmento.getBlocos(`) along with `setAssociation`, `addAssoc...` etc

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#belongs-to-many-associations

Comment: Hi Cam! Thanks so much for the reply, that was really helpful! You didn't misinterpreted, there's no n:m relationship in this case, one Apartment can have 0..1 Block only. Unfortunately it didn't work for me following your modification. I keep getting the error message saying "bloco_condominio (Apartamento) is not associated to apartamento" . 

By the way, sorry for forgetting to translate the models, you translated'em correctly.

Comment: I've just created local copies of your models to get it working on my machine.  First, I'd change the default time values to be `new Date()` rather than `sequelize.fn('now')`.  That's a side point though

Comment: .. hit enter too quickly on that last on... Anyway, I have it working (after removing the notNulls and the models not listed above.  The command to get the apartments that belong to a block is: `bloco.getApartmento()` because you have set an `as:`, sequelize won't pluralise the method name.

Comment: I am sorry, but I didn't really understand how to adapt this example to an Apartamento.findById() query and return it's block included considering both models already have their entries created in my database. What I actually need is to access the Block that a given Apartment belongs to, not the Apartments a Block has.

Comment: `Apartamento.findById(:id_apartamento, {
      include: [{
        model: Bloco
      }]
    })`  should work

Comment: Just testing `apartamento.getBloco()` (which I assumed would also work), and it only works when the `as: Bloco` is added to the `Apartamento.belongsTo(` definition. i.e. change it to:  `Apartamento.belongsTo(Bloco, { as: "Bloco", foreignKey: 'id_bloco' });` and then the `getBloco(` instance method will work.

Comment: Thanks so much! It wasn't working because of the `as: ` I was using. Would you mind explaining why is that and also why should I use `new Date()` instead of `sequelize.fn('now')`? Regardless this, thank you for your help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: I spun it up using MySQL and function as default values only work for postgres and sqlite.  IMO, if you're setting the default value in the Node domain, you should use a Javascript Date object.  The ORM can then convert that to the format suitable for the database.  That's just my point of view on it though... In this instance, I had to change your definition to work with MySQL.  Glad to help Enrico :)